# How to use kotlin to define an Android Application class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

My code:

```
 object MyApplication : Application() {

      override fun onCreate() {
          super.onCreate()
          initOkHttp()
      }
   }
```

when I declare `MyApplication` in `AndroidManifest`, it says `has no default constructor`.

Can anybody help?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution ais to use the `class` keyword instead of `object`. An [`object` declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) in Kotlin is a singleton, which means it only has a single instance, and it has a private constructor to prevent the creation of any other instances.

In the case of an `Application` class on Android however, the framework itself will create the instance when your application launches, and this requires an accessible private constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following where in the type is changed to class from object

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
      initOkHttp()
  }
}
```

Comment: I use this and i get unresolved reference: Application, while in Java all works ok

Answer (score 1):

You should use `class` instead of `Object`, to make it work.

```
 class MyApplication : Application() {
      override fun onCreate() {
          super.onCreate()
          initOkHttp()
      }
   }
```

Comment: I use this and i get unresolved reference: Application, while in Java all works ok

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is because the `object` modifier effectively makes your class a singleton, therefore there's no practical way for it to be instantiated. Therefore replace it with `class` which is the equivalent of an ordinary Java class.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can create an application class

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
   override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
  }
}
```